# Remote browser session debugging: Is there a tool to get a "core dump" of a browser's interaction with a webpage?

Tags: browser, web-development, debug, dump

A user of my website is having a problem that I can't reproduce. It is maddening to debug, because all I can really ask the user (nontechnical person) is their OS version and browser version.

Is there an extension for Chrome/Firefox, or any other software, that can basically record the user's session with a webpage from the client perspective? Akin to everything you'd see in the Chrome Developer toolbar, recorded into a "dump" file that I could analyze? Files downloaded, DOM loaded, javascript events, etc.

Comment: What is the problem, i.e. how is it manifesting itself?

Comment: Specifically, it's some issue with playback from a video provider I use. But really my question is general purpose... does such a tool exist?

Comment: Not sure if this is an option but would the user be open to a TeamViewer or [join.me](https://www.join.me) session so that you can get access to their PC? In all honestly this would be a less technical solution than what you are proposing.